# How to read out point position of a given plot in matplotlib?(without using mouse)

Tags: python, matplotlib

The case is, I have a 2D array and can convert it to a plot. How can I read the y value of a point with given x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the input data that you used to generate the plot. Either this is a mathematical function which you can just evaluate for a given `x` or this is a two-dimensional data set which you can search for any given `x`. In the latter case, if `x` is not contained in the data set, you might want to interpolate or throw an error.

Comment: o thanks! I wasn't familiar with neither scipy nor the interpolate method before, but I'm sure this'll solve my problem:)